# Find all by primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I have a cassandra table:

| pk | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk_1 | key_1 | value_1 |
| pk_1 | key_2 | value_2 |
| pk_1 | key_3 | value_3 |

where `pk` and `key` form a compound key (`pk` is partition key, and `key` is clustering).

I want to retrieve all `key`-`value` pairs by `pk` using Spring JPA to get `Map<String, String>` as a result.

I have tried with the following:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityCompoundKey> {
    @Query("SELECT key, value FROM my_table WHERE pk='?0'")
    Map<String, String> getAll(String pk);

    // other crud methods
}
```

However, when calling it with `pk_1` as the parameter, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 3
```

How can I fix it? Is there a better approach to retrieve elements by primary key only?

**EDIT**

```
@Table
public class MyEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    pribate MyEntityCompoundKey key;
    
    @CassandraType(type = Name.Text)
    private String value;
}

@PrimaryKeyClass
public class MyEntityCompoundKey {
  
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "pk", type= PARTITIONED)
    private String pk;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "key", type = CLUSTERED)
    private String key;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `pk` is the *partition key*, not primary key. PRIMARY KEY = partition key + clustering column. :)

Comment: so in Database you have multiple rows for the same PK. How can that be? Maybe you mean the primary key is the combination of pk and key

Comment: @Boug yes, my mistake, check other comment. I will correct that.

Comment: @Forin please provide the code for MyEntity and MyEntityCompoundKey and I will post a very clean solution

Comment: @Boug I've edited the post.

Comment: @Forin check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write in your repository a method with signature

```
public interface MyRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityCompoundKey> {
    List<MyEntity> findByKeyPk(String pk)
}
```

which will be automatically implemented by spring and do what you want.